# Mixare - How to display local data

Tags: java, android

After a make a call for a web service to get POIs from a database and show them in a list, I then click a button that opens up the camera displaying these POIs thanks to Mixare **that I imported into my app**. The problem is that Mixare only accepts URLs to be passed on to get data. Like so :

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://ws.geon ames.org/findNearbyWikipediaJSON"), "application/mixare-json");
startActivity(i);
```

Has anyone succeeded to use local data in Mixare ?

NB: I can't make another call to the web service, I want to be able to use the data I already have